# How to call a method with a variable parameter from the main method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, parameters, call

I would like to call the isATens method from my main method but im only able to do that when isATens has no parameter. I'v tried putting the same parameter in the caller, but that does't seem to recognize that either.

```
public class P1L4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P1L4 main = new P1L4();
        main.run();
        isATens(userInput); //<--- this is what I've tried doing.
    }

    public void run() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name a tens and i'll test if it's one under 100.");
        int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public boolean isATens(int userInput) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
        switch (userInput) {
            case 10 : case 20 : case 30 : case 40 : case 50 : case 60: case 70: case 80: case 90 :
                isUnderOneHundred(continued);
            default :
                System.out.println("Not under one hundred");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isUnderOneHundred(int continued) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: userInput is not a variable, nor is it a value.try with: isATens(5), or isATens(<insertAnyNumericalIntegerValueHere>). also, since isATens is not a static method, you need to call it through an instance of your class

Comment: also you have to call main.isAtens(5). and isUnderOneHundred method is pointless.

Comment: in `run` method : `isAtens(userInput)` after the `Scanner` reading.

Comment: @Stultuske How is userInput not a variable? isn't it declared with int Userinput = scanner.nextInt();?

Comment: local within your run method, yes, but you try to use it in your main method, there it is an unknown

Comment: You are declaring variable userInput in a different scope of calling it. It should be the other way around. First declare it in the main before calling the function, then scan it in main and then call the function in main. Secondly the methods you call from static context must be static

Answer (score 1):

There are some Java concepts that you apparently haven't learned yet: Scope and Instance vs. static methods. Read the appropriate chapters of your Java textbook if you have difficulties understanding my following comments.

`int userInput = scanner.nextInt();` is declared inside the scope of the `run()` method, and therefore not visible in the `main()` method. If you want to see `userInput` outside of the run() method, I'd make it the return value of that method:

```
public int run() {
    ...
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    return userInput;
}
```

You're mixing instance and static methods without any visible concept when to use which kind. When you want to call an instance method from a static one, you need to name the instance before the dot, so at least it has to be `main.isATens(userInput);` instead of `isATens(userInput);` (after you've solved the `userInput` issue).

Your program logic is strange, e.g. I'd expect a method like `isUnderOneHundred(int continued)` to return true if the parameter is under 100, but that method doesn't even have any look at its parameter and returns true for any number you pass in.